# Makefile cant find directories C++

Tags: c++, makefile

I am working on a project related to Chess and I use a makefile to compile everything. My goal is to compile only files that have been changed,instead of everything everytime. Folder structure can be seen clearer [here](https://github.com/wawaroutas/chess). `make main.o` results in an error :

```
fatal error: chesspieces.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include "chesspieces.h"
```

And pretty much everything else gives me a `No rule to make target .o . Stop`. I am using make from chess/src and I have every folder included in my `Includes` variable. Make file here:

```
CC = g++
INCLUDES =-Icomponents -IBoard -Ipieces -IApplication
OUTPUT = -o Chess

Chess: main.o board.o player.o chess.o
    $(CC) main.o board.o player.o chess.o $(OUTPUT)

main.o: main.cc board.h chess.h player.h chesspieces.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c main.cc

position.o: position.cc position.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c position.cc
    
piece.o: piece.cc piece.h color.h position.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c piece.cc

rook.o: rook.cc rook.h piece.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c rook.cc

queen.o: queen.cc queen.h piece.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c queen.cc

pawn.o: pawn.cc pawn.h piece.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c pawn.cc

knight.o: knight.cc knight.h piece.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c knight.cc

king.o: king.cc king.h piece.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c king.cc

bishop.o: bishop.cc bishop.h piece.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c bishop.cc

square.o: square.cc square.h color.h position.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c square.cc

board.o: board.cc board.h square.h position.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c board.cc

player.o: player.cpp player.h board.h piece.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c player.cc

chess.o: chess.cc chess.h player.h board.h piece.h
    $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c chess.cc
```

Making the dependencies my thinkings was to add every header included in the file,not sure about that

EDIT: Compiling on command line works fine(Besides the linking errors)
`g++ -Icomponents -IBoard -IPieces -Iapplication main.cc`
So something is wrong with the `$(INCLUDES)` variable,can't figure out why but it's blank: `g++    -c -o main.o main.cc main.cc:5:10: fatal error: chesspieces.h: No such file or directory`

[Folders1](https://prnt.sc/1th34ei)
[Folders2](https://prnt.sc/1th36lw)

Comment: Thank you for your response,something is wrong with my $(INCLUDES) .Make is runnning this command `g++    -c -o main.o main.cc
main.cc:5:10: fatal error: chesspieces.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include "chesspieces.h" // King, Queen, Rook, Knight, Bishop, Pawn`
and the header is under chess/src/components,which is added in my `$INCLUDES`

Comment: Please edit your question to add new information with formatting: comments can't be formatted.

Comment: Also please include all necessary information in the question: SO questions shouldn't link to remote images or source trees as these will disappear and then the question becomes not understandable for future people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you didn't make clear in your question is the structure of your directory, or the directory you were in when you ran `make`.  By reviewing the github repo we can see that your makefile is in the root directory and your source files are in subdirectories: for example you have `src/main.cc`, `src/Application/chess.cc`, etc.

But in your makefile, you don't provide any paths.  Your rules are:

```
main.o: main.cc board.h chess.h player.h chesspieces.h
        $(CC) $(INCLUDES) -c main.cc
```

These files you've mentioned here don't exist, so make will fail.  I'm actually confused about how you're getting the behavior you are: you should get errors like, *No rule to build main.cc* or something like that.

Maybe you're not running `make` in the root directory of your source tree, but rather somewhere else?  In that case `make` can't find your makefile and it's just using default rules, which explains why your `INCLUDES` variable is not found.

Comment: I apologise for that. I just added  screenshots with the structure. I am running make from chess/src. Running make from /chess gives me the errors that got you confused `C:\Users\ed\CppProjects\chess> make main.o
make: *** No rule to make target main.cc', needed by main.o.  Stop.`

Comment: Well, I mean, make isn't going to go looking around your filesystem to find things.  You have to tell it exactly where everything is, with proper directory paths.  If you run `make` from inside `chess/src` then it can't find your makefile, because there's no `chess/src/makefile`.  And, if your source files are in some other directory make can't find them if you don't use the path.  You'll need to edit your makefile to add the appropriate paths to your rules for the sources and headers, then run from the directory containing the makefile (or use `-f` argument to make).

Comment: So the rules should have the paths in them,right? For example : `main.o: src/main.cc src/board.h` etc?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly what the paths are depends on which directory you're in when you start make.

Comment: Adding paths fixed the problem thank you. I will accept this as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'INCLUDES' of the 'Makefile' file contains command line switches that tell the compiler in which directory to look for include files.  The '-Ipieces' key tells the compiler to look for include files in the subdirectory named 'pieces' of the current directory. The file 'chesspieces.h' should be in one of the subdirecties that enumerated in variable 'INCLUDES'.